# How to customize the TimePicker?

Tags: android, time, customization

I'm creating an app which will have a countdown timer.
I would like to choose the time by TimePicker (after clicking a button).
I would like to have only a few choices. It is 15,30,45 minutes.

Unfortunately TimePicker is not exactly what I wanted.

Is there any possibility to edit TimePicker, to show only a custom set of values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than showing a `TimePicker` for choosing `15`, `30` or `45` minutes, you should use a `Spinner`

If you don't know how to use a spinner tell me in the comment!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that using reflection. I am not sure if it is a right thing to do though.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/aragaer/jtt_android/blob/old_dirty/src/com/aragaer/jtt/JttPickerDialog.java) of how it could be done. Line 60 replaces the 24-hour spinner with 12 Japanese symbols in android earlier than 3.0. Lines 74-76 do the same for 3.0+.

It might be better to create your own dialog with spinners, but for my code I wanted to mimic the native TimePicker.